# add some Functions link down payment, Length of Loan, monthly or biweekly button add in loan calculator

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

(let's say they click >>)Financing Terms: Page 2

Set your down payment, loan term, and payment frequency that suit the financing terms

you prefer.

Down Payment: customer can choose any amount(values being $5K, $10K, $15 K, $20K

or they can put any amount in a box)

Length of Loan: 36 months, 48 months, 60 months, 72 months, 84 months

[Option to choose in form of a button ]>Biweekly OR Monthly

$252/biweekly payment (for example) * it will show the biweekly payment or monthly

payment based on the preferences selected (this is calculated automatically )

Customer Requirements Document

Customer Link : https://www.clutch.ca/financing/loan-calculator

[My Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv0LM.png)

My Link : https://www.splitarts.net/smr/financing/

```
<?php
global $listing_id;

$listing_id = ( is_null( $listing_id ) ) ? get_the_ID() : $listing_id;

$currency_symbol = stm_get_price_currency();
$price           = get_post_meta( $listing_id, 'price', true );
$sale_price      = get_post_meta( $listing_id, 'sale_price', true );

if ( ! empty( $sale_price ) ) {
    $price = apply_filters( 'get_conver_price', $sale_price );
} elseif ( ! empty( $price ) ) {
    $price = apply_filters( 'get_conver_price', $price );
} else {
    $price = '';
}

$wide_calculator = '';

if ( ! empty( $wide_version ) && 'yes' === $wide_version ) {
    $wide_calculator = 'wide-version';
}

$label_font_size = ( ! empty( $label_font_size ) ) ? 'heading-font' : '';

?>
<div class="stm_auto_loan_calculator <?php echo esc_attr( $wide_calculator ); ?>">
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
            <div class="stm_auto_loan_calculator_bg">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php if ( ! empty( $title ) ) : ?>
                        <div class="title single-calculator-title">
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                            <img src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/dollers.svg">
                            <?php //echo wp_kses( $title_icon, apply_filters( 'stm_ew_kses_svg', array() ) ); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
                                <<?php echo esc_attr( $title_tag ); ?>
                                    class="heading-font"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></<?php echo esc_attr( $title_tag ); ?>>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <!--Amount-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="labeled <?php echo esc_attr( $label_font_size ); ?>">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Vehicle price', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?> <span
                                class="orange">(<?php echo esc_html( $currency_symbol ); ?>)</span></div>
                    <!-- <input type="text" class="numbersOnly vehicle_price" value="<?php //echo esc_attr( $price ); ?>"/> -->
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8">
                        <input class='range__slider' id='slider' max='999999' min='0' oninput='amount.value=slider.value' type='range' value='300'>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="currency-wrap">
                        <span class="currency-code">$</span>
                         <input class='numbersOnly vehicle_price' id='amount' oninput='slider.value=amount.value' type='text' value="0<?php echo esc_attr( $price ); ?>">
                    </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <!--Interest rate-->
                        <div class="form-group md-mg-rt">
                            <div class="labeled <?php echo esc_attr( $label_font_size ); ?>">
                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Interest rate', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?> <span class="orange">(%)</span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="numbersOnly interest_rate" value="<?php echo esc_html( $default_interest_rate ); ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <!--Period-->
                        <div class="form-group md-mg-lt">
                            <div class="labeled <?php echo esc_attr( $label_font_size ); ?>">
                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Loan Term', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>
                                <span class="orange">(<?php esc_html_e( 'month', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>)</span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="numbersOnly period_month" value="<?php echo esc_html( $default_month_period ); ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Down Payment-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="labeled <?php echo esc_attr( $label_font_size ); ?>">
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Down Payment', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>
                        <span class="orange">(<?php echo esc_html( $currency_symbol ); ?>)</span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <input type="text" class="numbersOnly down_payment" value="12<?php echo esc_html( $default_down_payment ); ?>"/>
                </div>   
                



                <a href="" class="button button-sm calculate_loan_payment dp-in"><?php esc_html_e( 'Calculate', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?></a>
                <div class="calculator-alert alert alert-danger"></div>
            </div>    
        </div>

        <!--Results-->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="stm_calculator_bg">
                <div class="stm_calculator_results" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="stm-calc-results-inner">
                    <div class="row">    
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1">
                            <img src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/pay-per-click.svg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-11">
                            <div class="stm-calc-label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Monthly Payment', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?></div>
                            <div class="monthly_payment h5"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">    
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1">
                            <img src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/paymnet.svg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-11">
                            <div class="stm-calc-label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total Interest Payment', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?></div>
                            <div class="total_interest_payment h5"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">    
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1">
                            <img src="https://www.splitarts.net/smr/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/total.svg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-11">
                            <div class="stm-calc-label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total Amount to Pay', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?></div>
                            <div class="total_amount_to_pay h5"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if ( ! empty( $label_font_size ) ) : ?>
    <style>
        .stm_auto_loan_calculator .labeled.heading-font {
            margin-bottom: 9px;
            font-size: <?php echo esc_attr( $label_font_size ); ?>px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #232628;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .stm_auto_loan_calculator .labeled.heading-font .orange {
            font-weight: 400;
        }
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart ?>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var vehicle_price;
            var interest_rate;
            var down_payment;
            var period_month;

            var stmCurrency = "<?php echo esc_js( stm_get_price_currency() ); ?>";
            var stmPriceDel = "<?php echo esc_js( apply_filters( 'stm_me_get_nuxy_mod', ' ', 'price_delimeter' ) ); ?>";
            var stmCurrencyPos = "<?php echo esc_js( apply_filters( 'stm_me_get_nuxy_mod', 'left', 'price_currency_position' ) ); ?>";

            $('.calculate_loan_payment').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                //Useful vars
                var current_calculator = $(this).closest('.stm_auto_loan_calculator');

                var calculator_alert = current_calculator.find('.calculator-alert');
                //First of all hide alert
                calculator_alert.removeClass('visible-alert');

                //4 values for calculating
                vehicle_price = parseFloat(current_calculator.find('input.vehicle_price').val());

                interest_rate = parseFloat(current_calculator.find('input.interest_rate').val());
                interest_rate = interest_rate / 1200;

                down_payment = parseFloat(current_calculator.find('input.down_payment').val());
                
                period_month = parseFloat(current_calculator.find('input.period_month').val());

                //Help vars

                var validation_errors = true;

                var monthly_payment = 0;
                var total_interest_payment = 0;
                var total_amount_to_pay = 0;

                //Check if not nan
                if (isNaN(vehicle_price)) {
                    calculator_alert.text("<?php esc_html_e( 'Please fill Vehicle Price field', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>");
                    calculator_alert.addClass('visible-alert');
                    current_calculator.find('input.vehicle_price').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    validation_errors = true;
                } else if (isNaN(interest_rate)) {
                    calculator_alert.text("<?php esc_html_e( 'Please fill Interest Rate field', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>");
                    calculator_alert.addClass('visible-alert');
                    current_calculator.find('input.interest_rate').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    validation_errors = true;
                } else if (isNaN(period_month)) {
                    calculator_alert.text("<?php esc_html_e( 'Please fill Period field', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>");
                    calculator_alert.addClass('visible-alert');
                    current_calculator.find('input.period_month').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    validation_errors = true;
                } else if (isNaN(down_payment)) {
                    calculator_alert.text("<?php esc_html_e( 'Please fill Down Payment field', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>");
                    calculator_alert.addClass('visible-alert');
                    current_calculator.find('input.down_payment').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    validation_errors = true;
                } else if (down_payment > vehicle_price) {
                    //Check if down payment is not bigger than vehicle price
                    calculator_alert.text("<?php esc_html_e( 'Down payment can not be more than vehicle price', 'motors-elementor-widgets' ); ?>");
                    calculator_alert.addClass('visible-alert');
                    current_calculator.find('input.down_payment').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    validation_errors = true;
                } else {
                    validation_errors = false;
                }

                if (!validation_errors) {
                    var interest_rate_unused = interest_rate;

                    if (interest_rate == 0) {
                        interest_rate_unused = 1;
                    }

                    monthly_payment = (vehicle_price - down_payment) * interest_rate_unused * Math.pow(1 + interest_rate, period_month);

                    var monthly_payment_div = ((Math.pow(1 + interest_rate, period_month)) - 1);

                    if (monthly_payment_div == 0) {
                        monthly_payment_div = 1;
                    }

                    monthly_payment = monthly_payment / monthly_payment_div;
                    monthly_payment = monthly_payment.toFixed(2);

                    total_amount_to_pay = down_payment + (monthly_payment * period_month);
                    total_amount_to_pay = total_amount_to_pay.toFixed(2);

                    total_interest_payment = total_amount_to_pay - vehicle_price;
                    total_interest_payment = total_interest_payment.toFixed(2);

                    current_calculator.find('.stm_calculator_results').slideDown();
                    current_calculator.find('.monthly_payment').text(stm_get_price_view(monthly_payment, stmCurrency, stmCurrencyPos, stmPriceDel));
                    current_calculator.find('.total_interest_payment').text(stm_get_price_view(total_interest_payment, stmCurrency, stmCurrencyPos, stmPriceDel));
                    current_calculator.find('.total_amount_to_pay').text(stm_get_price_view(total_amount_to_pay, stmCurrency, stmCurrencyPos, stmPriceDel));
                } else {
                    current_calculator.find('.stm_calculator_results').slideUp();
                    current_calculator.find('.monthly_payment').text('');
                    current_calculator.find('.total_interest_payment').text('');
                    current_calculator.find('.total_amount_to_pay').text('');
                }
            })

            $(".numbersOnly").on("keypress keyup blur", function (event) {
                //this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
                if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                }
            });
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
<?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd ?>
```